# Default text editor for all text fields in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

Is there a way to set the default editor to wysihtml5 editor for textfields in all my models? I am able to do it on an individual model basis like this in rails_admin initializer file:

```
config.model Article do
    edit do
      field :title
      field :subtitle
      field :author
      field :cover_photo
      field :active
      field :content, :wysihtml5
    end   
end
```

I was wondering if there was a quick and easy way to do it so any model with a field of type "text" will be edited by wysihtml5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at `config/initializers/core_extensions.rb`

as in

```
# config/initializers/core_extensions.rb
class ActiveRecord::Base
  # common code here
  def self.for_all_models
    # code
  end
end
```

Comment: I found a way in the RailsAdmin DSL to apply stuff for all models, check the last para in this link https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Railsadmin-DSL
And then there is a method called fields_of_type which should let me select only fields of type "Text", I have been playing with this but no luck so far. Check this link: http://rubydoc.info/github/sferik/rails_admin/RailsAdmin/Config/Fields/Group:fields_of_type